# use id from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok I have some legacy JS that get results from a users test, i have this JS file refrenced in my code so i can use the `ID results-percentile-2`in my HTML as so

```
your score 
<span id="results-percentile-2"></span>%
```

However I have a piece of javascript I would like to call the ID in instead of in the HTML

```
<script>
        function move() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
            var width = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 40) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    width++;
                    elem.style.width = width + '%';
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I would like to use `results-percentile-2` to set the width, I have tried

```
<script>
        function move() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
            var width = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2")) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    width++;
                    elem.style.width = width + '%';
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

but is this the correct way of doing it as its not working, or should i point to the correct js file the id is in for example

```
if (width >= myjavascript.js.getElementById("results-percentile-2"))
```

UPDATE

This is the Legacy code im geting the js from

```
$("#next-button")
        .click(function () {
            a.eventHub.publish("ui/nextclick")
        }), this.showView("test")
}, UI.prototype.updatePercentile = function (a) {
    if (this.isStandalone || -1 == a.percentile) $("#results-percentages")
        .hide();
    else {
        $("#results-percentages")
            .show(), $("#results-percentile-1")
            .html(a.percentile), $("#results-suffix")
            .html(a.suffix), $("#results-suffix-2")
            .html(a.suffix), 1 === a.timesTaken ? ($("#results-timestaken")
            .html(a.timesTaken + " time"), $("#results-percentile-2")
            .html("100")) : ($("#results-timestaken")
            .html(a.timesTaken + " times"), $("#results-percentile-2")
            .html(a.percentile));
        var b = 0;
        $("#percentile-scale .scale-item")
            .each(function () {
                b += $(this)
                    .outerWidth()
            }), $("#percentile-scale .scale-indicator")
            .css("width", b * a.percentile / 100 + "%"),
            $(".scale-marker")
                .css("left", b * a.percentile / 100 + "%")

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Heu @AlexBass Yes i can, ill update my answer once i have

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=J06PvTxiqP  link to fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this statement

```
if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2"))
```

you are comparing a value with an object (a [SPAN]).

You must change your statement to

```
if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2").innerHTML)
```

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. however the script to set the width of a progress bar is now not working.

Comment: I simulated that behavior with a div and it's working, take a look at this sample https://jsfiddle.net/berets/u7s2f9vp/

Comment: Thanks, Ill see if i can fix it, when i get it working ill accept your answer

Comment: If you add your other code to fiddle I could help you to fix it

Comment: Thanks Luca, Ill do that now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=J06PvTxiqP here is the link, the #results-percentile wont do much as no database connection but this this is the syntax

Comment: but <span id="results-percentile-2"></span>%  where is ?

Comment: in a different part of the HTML, im no longer using that as I am trying to show the percentage via the progress bar, Ill update the js to include the old text

Comment: ok but javascript need to access that tag, you should add it to fiddle

Comment: doing so now, should be on the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/berets/txtm9y9f/5/ this way it's working, but missing items doesn't stop it

Comment: wow, just seen. let me try it on my server. but looks amazing, thanks you for your time. 3 mins

Comment: Update, it seems the code is now blocking some other parts of the site, ill work on these then accept your answer, thanks again